# Can't get angular 7 to route when deployed on a Kubernetes Ingress Path

Tags: angular, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am unable to get my Angular to Route after its deployed on via Kubernetes Ingress Path. It works in dev mode, it works when navigate to the service node port ip address, (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:pppp) but on the host.com/op. Example host.com/op/page - no routing to page.

Ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: [redacted]
spec:
  rules:
  - host: host.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName:service-a
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /api/*
        backend:
          serviceName: service-b
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /op/*
        backend:
          serviceName: angular7-nginx-service
          servicePort: 80
  backend:
    serviceName: service-a
    servicePort: 80
```

My nginx server conf file

```
server {
  listen 80;
  charset utf-8;
  sendfile on;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  location / {
    expires -1;
    add_header Pragma "no-cache";
    add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html = 404;
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using Nginx ingress-controller? it's a more scalable solution for exposing your services

Comment: my issue is that it hits the server that has the angular app but I get no angular routing when I use Ingress as my load balancer.

Comment: I am facing same issue with Latest azure kubernetes version .Any updates ?

Comment: not yet. At least on my side

Comment: I got that, what I'm suggesting is to have the nginx ingress controller do the routing for you instead of the config. Run the following `helm install stable/nginx-ingress` and then add `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx` in your ingress annotations.

Comment: did it, and it didn't change the results.